# TVirtualStringTree - How to change the [-] / [+] buttons?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

How can I use my own custom buttons (images) to replace the default `[-]`/`[+]` buttons in the VST?
I want to use arrows instead ([image], [image]), but also to support RTL bidi mode ([image], [image]).

edit: I am aware of the `bsTriangle` style (ButtonStyle). It does not respect RTL. I want to use my own custom images.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aren't those images usually in Windows Vista and Windows 7? The tree control should get them automatically on those systems when you have themes enabled.

The easy way to get something close to that is to just set the `ButtonStyle` property to `bsTriangle`. It won't be exactly the images shown in the question, though. The "minus" arrow will point straight down instead of diagonally, and the "plus" arrow will be solid instead of an outline.

You can provide your own bitmap. Change the VT_XPBUTTONMINUS and VT_XPBUTTONPLUS resources to whatever images you want, and set the `ButtonFillMode` property to `fmShaded`.

I see no facility for changing the image based on the bi-di mode, though. You can create a descendant class that overrides `PaintNodeButton`, and then paint whatever you want. Copy the placement code from the parent class.

Comment: Thank you sir. It seems like overriding `PaintNodeButton` is the only choice.

Answer (score 8):

IIRC you get it by including toUseExplorerTheme in PaintOptions. However this also changes the selection look (to the better IMNSHO) and probably more.

For example if I drop a `TVirtualStringTree` on a form and add the following event handlers:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VT.RootNodeCount := 10;
  VT.TreeOptions.PaintOptions := VT.TreeOptions.PaintOptions + [toUseExplorerTheme];
  VT.OnInitNode := VTInitNode;
  VT.OnInitChildren := VTInitChildren;
end;

procedure TForm1.VTInitChildren(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; var ChildCount: Cardinal);
begin
  ChildCount := 3;
end;

procedure TForm1.VTInitNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  ParentNode, Node: PVirtualNode; var InitialStates: TVirtualNodeInitStates);
begin
  Include(InitialStates, ivsHasChildren);
end;
```

I get
[image: screenshot with triangular markers]

**Edit:** Unfortunately, setting `Form1.BiDiMode` to `bdRightToLeft` yields
[image: screenshot with wrong triangular markers]
on my German Windows 7. I don't know if this works better on Arabic or Hebrew systems.

Comment: What version of VirtualTrees are you using?

Comment: @ZigiZ: The cooment at the top of VirtualTrees.pas says `Version 5.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

See the `ButtonStyle` property. Not sure does it respect the RTL bidi mode thought.

Comment: I am aware of the `bsTriangle` style. it does not respect RTL. I want to use my own image.